# Reinstalling MS Project on a new computer with old key?

Tags: microsoft-office, reinstall, license-key, microsoft-project

About 3 years ago I purchased MS Office Project Standard 2007 and installed it on my Vista notebook. Now I'd like to use the same piece of software on my new Win7 x64 notebook. Unfortunately I lost the installation CD since, but I managed to recover the original key via a utility called [Magical Jelly Bean Key Finder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/).

I located the install package for Project Standard 2007 at [CNet](http://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Office-Project-Standard-2007/3000-2076_4-10704822.html), and started to install it on the new Win7 notebook, but when prompted to enter my product key, it does not recognize it as a valid key.

Do I have any options to use the same old Project 2007 on my new notebook with the original product key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked and there is no OEM version, so that rules that out. I also looked to see what other versions there may be. I had one in mind, and it is the ONLY other version, so that must be it.

You probably need Office Project Professional.

Update: We did a remote session, got the right software, and the key worked fine.

Comment: Hmm I only found the trial version here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20599 and it also did not accept the licence key. Will PM you. Thanks for looking into this.